# svelte-select doesnot working when clicking on select menu doesnot open

Tags: select, svelte

I am using svelte-select on my svelte.js Project. its getting selected value but when click on it nothing happens seems its not working

```
    <script>
     import Select from 'svelte-select';
     const languages = ['English', 'Korean'];
    </script>


     <Select
    items={languages}
    showChevron={true}
    searchable={false}
    value={'English'}
    clearable={false}
    focused={false}
    >
   </Select>
```

Comment: i just tried in the svelte repl, and it's working. You will have to give more details in order to reproduce this.

Comment: https://svelte.dev/repl/2e598b3e388d46248dd71be7f415383d?version=4.1.1